# Do Something When MsgBox Is Closed

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, msgbox, nsbasic

I'm making a program in NS BASIC/CE that shows the user a warning, but when the user closes the `MsgBox`(clicking in OK), I want that the application executes `AfterWarn` Sub. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I read a little wrong
But her:

```
Dim varResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
vResult = Msgbox("Are you sure you wanted to make this change?.",vbOkCancel)
If result = vbOk Then
    AfterWarn()
Else
   'Do something else?
End if
```